# How to fix “The ConnectionString property has not been initialized” in nopCommerce

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, nopcommerce, ysod

I'm trying to integrate nopCommerce into a third party system but am hitting a problem when I try to access any nopCommerce pages. Because I'm integrating with a third party system I've had to merge web.configs and copy all files over. I have a standalone install of nopCommerce aswell and that is running fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error I am getting is as follows:

---

The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand() +5038498
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection) +20
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +52

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +161
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +98
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +81
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +46
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +44
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) +151
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector) +90
   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Configuration.Settings.SettingManager.GetAllSettings() +542
   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Configuration.Settings.SettingManager.GetSettingByName(String name) +121
   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Configuration.Settings.SettingManager.GetSettingValue(String name) +49
   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Configuration.Settings.SettingManager.GetSettingValueBoolean(String name, Boolean defaultValue) +54
   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Configuration.Settings.SettingManager.GetSettingValueBoolean(String name) +41
   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.CustomerManagement.CustomerManager.get_UsernamesEnabled() +45
   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Web.Administration.LoginPage.ApplyLocalization() +108
   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Web.Administration.LoginPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +40
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Web.BaseNopAdministrationPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +44
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

---

Comment: PS I'm using nopCommerce 1.80 and ISS 7 on Win 7 (.NET 4.0).

As I say, I have a standalone version working, it's the integration that's causing an issue, but not sure where.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a valid connection string for the NopCommerce database in web.config, and you need to ensure that it gets read.

At `Application_Start` in global.asax NopCommerce reads in the connection string and injects it into the business logic DLL. If that doesn't happen, the data access layer (in the business logic DLL) won't be able to open a connection and you'll get the error you just posted. I suggest check web.config and global.asax; if both look good put a breakpoint in `Application_Start`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a valid connection string.

After you pass the database installation phase (when you fill in the database settings) nop commerce is keeping the database information in a file that is not within the project, you can find it within the `App_Data folder` in the `Presentation\Nop.Web\App_Data\` named `Settings.txt`, update it if you need and run the application again.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is not held in the web.config file in nopcommerce... it is in the ConnectionStrings.config file. You might want to check for that file and copy it over if it is not there or put your connection string in there if the file is there and the string is not.